# When I run a tweepy python script nothing happens on the associated twitter account

Tags: python-3.x, tweepy

I've created a python script with tweepy that replies to suicidal tweets with a link to a support website.  However, nothing happens when I run the code and tweet with any of the code words on a different account.  I'm opening and running the .py file in command prompt.

Like I said, I've tried using the specific words that should trigger it but it does not reply.

```
import tweepy

#the following module is a file with the specific keys set in
#a dictionary to the given variable, don't want to show them due to 
#privacy/security 

from keys import keys

CONSUMER_KEY = keys['consumer_key']
CONSUMER_SECRET = keys['consumer_secret']
ACCESS_TOKEN = keys['access_token']
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = keys['access_token_secret']

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)    

twts = api.search(q="suicide")     

t = ['suicide',
    'kill myself',
    'hate myself',
    'Suicidal',
    'self-harm',
    'self harm']

for s in twts:
    for i in t:
        if i == s.text:
            sn = s.user.screen_name
            m = "@%s You are loved! For help, visit https://suicidepreventionlifeline.org/" % (sn)
            s = api.update_status(m, s.id)
```

It should reply with a help link, but it doesn't and I don't know what I did wrong in my code.  Any help?

Comment: The t array contains words you want to check in the tweet text ? if yes, you can remove "suicide" as the words is already present because it is in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Replace :

```
if i == s.text:
```

with :

```
if i in s.text:
```

Or to match words case sensitive, the best should be :

```
if i.lower() in s.text.lower():
```

Because `Suicidal` (an other words from the `t` array) can't be equal to the tweet text.
I guess you want to check if the text contains this word.